# Combining graphs for many countries from running the same do-file

Tags: graph, stata

I am using the same do-file for running the regressions for several countries. For this, I only change the name of the country in the "import dataset" part. I run the do-file for 1 country, a graph is produced. However, when I run the same do-file again for another country, previous graph disappears as I clear the results before running the same do-file.

Do you know any method for how I can combine the graphs produced for several countries by running the same do-file?

Comment: Use the `name()` and/or `saving()` options and the graph will stick around.  Using `saving()` or `graph export` is the safest strategy.

Comment: `graph combine` is how to do combine graphs. It is often much (much) better to plan at the outset for use of the `by()` option.  How much is "several"?